# How to stop iOS launch image moving up in Phonegap / Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch 1.1 / Phonegap 1.3 application and I've got a portrait and landscape launch image sized according to the iOS documentation.

When the app first launches, both launch images are correctly positioned.  Once the loading spinner is displayed, the launch image shifts vertically by a small amount leaving a white strip across the bottom of the screen (see image).  I've added a red border around the gap so it can be seen - the red border does not appear on the device.

[image]

How can I stop the launch image shifting vertically?

Comment: how do you display that loading spinner ?

Comment: The loading spinner is shown automatically by Phonegap I think.  I didn't write any code to show the spinner.  There is a Phonegap setting that allows the spinner to be turned off - the launch image still shifts up.

Comment: I tried to activate the option but I couldn't reproduce the bug. What version of phoneGap are you using ? How did you do to set the splash screen ?

Comment: I'm using Phonegap 1.3 and I just dragged the splash image into the Xcode project.  The image is the dimensions specified in the iOS guidelines.  Tomorrow I'll try the splash image on a new project and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just put it into APP_NAME/Resources/splash and name it Default.png and Default@2x and that works fine. Hope you solve it.

Comment: I created a brand new Phonegap project and named the files and it still shows the small white gap.

Comment: What's the size of you picture ?

Comment: Portrait is 768x1004 and Landscape is 1024x748

Comment: It looks like this is a Phonegap bug - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-263

Answer (score 0):

According to Shazron Abdullah: "The fix is indeed having 1024x768, and this is specific for Cordova's requirements since we are trying to "match" the behaviour of the default splashscreen and are doing transformations on it."

Looks like the issue is still unresolved and is a bug in PhoneGap/Cordova.

EDIT: Confirmed. This fix works using Cordova 1.5.0

Comment: What exactly is the fix? I'm using Cordova 1.6.1 and am having the same issue,

Comment: Fix is to use full size images instead of the cropped ones. For iPad it's: 768x1024 (2536x2048 - Retina) for Portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but I was able to solve it.

Make sure that while naming the splash screen file, you have included the .png extension as part of the name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I've edited your answer for readability; if I've inadvertently changed the meaning please feel free to edit it again or roll back the revision.  We do prefer that you avoid abbreviations (such as "u" for "you") and do not include tag lines.

Answer (score 0):

You must change in `config.xml` following lines:

```xml
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />    
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

and

```xml
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />   
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```