# Using AutoHideSplashScreen option with PhoneGap / Cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova, splash-screen

I have tried the [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SplashScreen) but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with Cordova. Without the plugin `navigator.splashscreen` isn't defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plugin should not be needed.

Set the key `AutoHideSplashScreen` to `NO` in Cordova.plist, then after device ready fires, use `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` to hide the splash screen.

It might be that you are not waiting till `deviceready` before trying to access `navigator.splashscreen`

*edit*

As mentioned by @respectTheCode below, as of 1.6 this has been removed and codified across platforms as `cordova.exec(null, null, “SplashScreen”, “hide”, [])`

Comment: Well it was that deviceready hadn't fired. In fact it isn't firing for me at all. I had a timeout that would start my app after a second so that I could test in a browser and thats why I never noticed.

Comment: As of 1.6 navigator.splashscreen has been removed. Use cordova.exec(null, null, “SplashScreen”, “hide”, []) instead.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I took RespectTheCode's advice and removed the device ready event out of the onLoad function. This is the working code. I'm putting the full code for other's who are learning:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    setTimeout(function() {
       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
       }, 1000);
</script>
```

The 1000 is one second. Will not work for less than one second i.e 500. Splash screen just hangs.

This is working for me. If code could be improved, feel free to answer it and I'll bump you up.

Also, PhoneGap/Cordova has a bug where you have to use splash images at the full size of the screen (768x1024). Follow the discussion here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-263

Or here: [How to stop iOS launch image moving up in Phonegap / Sencha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057472/how-to-stop-ios-launch-image-moving-up-in-phonegap-sencha-touch)