# Showing splash screen in PhoneGap/Cordova 1.5.0

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to get my splash screen to show for my PhoneGap/Cordova native iOS app. The default  or boolean for this behavior is set to 'YES'. I'm trying to get the screen to show for 2 seconds. At the moment, it only shows for a split second and then goes right into the app. Since my app does not download any data for the web on start, it loads pretty quickly.

According to this advice, this solution works for some. I'm using the latest Cordova 1.5.0 build: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/ios-phonegap-splash-screen-control/

I've turned the AutoHideSplashScreen to 'NO' in the Cordova.plist and I'm using this code:

```
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
               navigator.splashscreen.hide();
               }, 2000);
```

I've tried putting the setTimeout function within a function, but to no avail. Like so:

```
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function hideSplash() {
        setTimeout(function() {
                   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                   }, 2000);

    }
```

And then loading the 'hideSplash()' when the Body loads. But to no avail.

Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I didn't want to ask the same question twice, but this solution doesn't seem to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933988/with-phonegap-cordova-how-can-i-use-the-autohidesplashscreen-option/9967399#comment12733852_9967399

Comment: The 'device ready' is firing because I'm using using it also for checking internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I took RespectTheCode's advice and removed the device ready event out of the onLoad function. This is the working code. I'm putting the full code for other's who are learning:

```
<script>
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
   }, 1000);
</script>
```

The 1000 is one second for those who don't know. Will not work for less than one second i.e 500. Splash screen just hangs.

This is working for me when I install and app works fine,however, when I restart the device (iPad2) the splash screen hangs like the previous problem (above paragraph) and will not enter the app. Weird bug.

Anyone else experience this?

I'm on iOS 5.1 building with Xcode 4.3.1 and Cordova 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cordova 2.1.0 and now 2.2.0.
When calling navigator.splashscreen.hide(), the Splash Screen didn't disappear.
Using the following code, it worked:

```
    private static native void hideSplashScreen() /*-{
    $wnd.Cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
}-*/;
```

Hope this helps