# SyntaxError when calling navigator.splashscreen.hide() in Phonegap 1.9.0 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm working on a phonegap 1.9.0 app for android using ember and am trying to hide my splash screen once the app is loaded instead of waiting for the specified timeout.

My splash screen displays but I cannot successfully call

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide()
```

The inclusion of this line leads to the error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' at file:///android_asset/src/cordova-1.9.0.js:1012
```

I have tried downloading cordova-1.9.0.js again and using version 2.0.0 instead but encountered the same problem.

Here is my html/js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" title="master" type="text/css"       href="css/master.css" />
    <title>Cordova Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ember-0.9.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the Cordova API
            console.log("device ready...")
            navigator.splashscreen.hide()
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the activity code...

```
public class myApp extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/src/index.html", 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really weird as there is no good reason why it wouldn't work the way you have it setup. Did you make sure the SplashScreen plugin is in your list of plugins?

Comment: It wasn't! I think I was thrown by another post I read that said you shouldn't need to include a plugin - especially as the splash was showing without including the plugin, just not hiding. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code to hide splash screen:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
 }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately. It only disappears after the timeout has expired. Is there anything I need to setup to enable hiding it explicitly? Other posts mention

    "Set the key AutoHideSplashScreen to NO in Cordova.plist"

but I don't think I have a "Cordova.plist".

Comment: cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []); This line worked fine for me in Cordova 2.0 . Can you try your code in 2.0. Plist file exists for iOS only

Comment: I've got it sorted now, I wasn't including the required SplashScreen plug-in in the list of plug-ins. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my previous answer: [Splash Screen in Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968295/showing-splash-screen-in-phonegap-cordova-1-5-0/13601594#13601594)

I am using Cordova 2.1.0 and now 2.2.0. When calling navigator.splashscreen.hide(), the Splash Screen didn't disappear. Using the following code, it worked:

```
private static native void hideSplashScreen() /*-{
    $wnd.Cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
}-*/;
```

Hope this helps